# How to serialize objects created by factories

Tags: c#, serialization, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm working on a project that uses dependency injection via Ninject. So far, it is working out very well, and I'm liking DI a lot, but now I have decided I need to serialize some objects, and I'm finding it difficult to do that following DI patterns.

Say I have a class called Foo, which has a list of Bars, and makes them through a factory, like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private List<Bar> _bars;
    private BarFactory _barFactory;

    ...

    public void MakeBar()
    {
         _bars.Add(_barFactory.MakeBar());
    }
}
```

Here's Bar, which gets made when `_barFactory.MakeBar()` gets called. I want Bar to be serializable:

```
public class Bar : ISerializable
{
    private List<IPickle> _pickles;
    private PickleFactory _pickleFactory;

    public Bar(PickleFactory factory)
    {
         _pickleFactory = factory;
    }

    public void MakePickle(int x)
    {
         _pickles.Add(_pickleFactory.MakePickle(x));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        //serialize member variables here
    }

    //Constructor called during deserialization
    private Bar(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        //fill in member variables with data from SerializationInfo
    }
}
```

Notice that Bar has its own factory and a collection of pickles. Here's the problem: when the deserialization constructor of Bar gets called, I don't have any way to get it another PickleFactory. The original PickleFactory was given to Bar by the BarFactory, but the deserialization constructor wasn't called by BarFactory.

My current plan to solve this problem would be to extract all the serializable members of Bar into its own class called BarDataObject. Then I would make the BarDataObject serializable, but not Bar itself. I would add a function to BarFactory which accepts a BarDataObject as a parameter and builds a Bar for you filled in with all the information from the BarDataObject.

However, suppose Pickle *also* has service classes which it got from the factory that made it, which can't be serialized either. So I would have to extract a DataObject from Pickle as well, and my BarDataObject would have to hold onto a PickleDataObject. And suppose Pickle had a member variable with a mix of data and services too? I would have to make and maintain a DataObject for that as well. This seems like a real bummer, especially considering my project has many other things which I need to serialize, and they'll probably face the same problem.

So is there a better solution? Am I doing something wrong, DI-wise? I've just started working with DI and Ninject, but I can't seem to find anyone who's come up with a good way to serialize objects which got injected with service classes.

Comment: Can you add a constructor to your `BarFactory` class that accepts the serialization info?

Comment: What type of object is Foo? Is it a 'newable' or an 'injectable'? (http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/).

Comment: @Matthew - If I did, how would I get the SerializationInfo to the factory? By the time Bar's private constructor has been called, it is too late to ask the factory to make the Bar, since we're already in the Bar constructor, and Bar doesn't know about BarFactory in any case.

Comment: The fundamental problem: DI is top-down construction, but serialization is bottom-up.  You'll have to treat each construction path differently.  It ain't gonna be pretty.  POCOs and meta-objects will simplify things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my experience, only service classes should have dependencies, and service classes should never be subject to serialization.

The fact that you have a class that you want to serialize, but which relies on an injected service, seems like a code smell to me.

It's difficult to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish with `Bar`, but from what I can see, I'd suggest making `Pickle` be a POCO, and using a `List<Pickle>` instead of a custom `Bar` class.

Or, if `Bar` is intended to have other serializable information besides the Pickles, make `Bar` a POCO with a Pickles property:

```
public class Bar
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Pickle> Pickles {get;set;}
}
```

Because POCOs won't have dependencies, they shouldn't require factories, so this class should be entirely serializable. If there are complex functions that you'd like to perform on `Bar`s and `Pickle`s, they should be abstracted out into separate utility services that take `Bar`s and `Pickle`s as their method parameters.

Comment: I agree with StripingWarrior: You should separate data and behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems like it might work for my immediate problem. Basically, you are suggesting I take all of the services out of Bar and Pickle, and have Foo talk to those services (like the factories) instead? Fine. But what if later I also need to serialize Foo? Do I make Foo a POCO as well, and move all of the services for Foos, Bars, and Pickles into the guy that made Foo? Isn't that eventually going to result in a big ugly class that has way too many responsibilities?

Comment: @tandersen: It sounds like you understand the principle. It's the same strategy suggested in the article Mark Seeman linked to in his comment. (Mark literally wrote the book on DI in .NET, by the way). I think you'll find it pretty easy to separate responsibilities and keep class sizes small if you follow this pattern. If not, feel free to post a new question and see if the SO community can point out some useful patterns for your particular case.